# Configure CSSTidy selector sorting

Tags: css, sorting, properties, csstidy

How do I configure the order that CSSTidy uses to sort the properties?

I would like to use the box model sorting for CSS selectors (outside to inside), but I tried setting `"sort_properties": "true"` but the sorting doesn't seem to take place. The result is:

```
#background {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%
}
#background img {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 top:10px;
 min-width:1100px;
 padding-top:95px;
 position:absolute
}
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krLkK/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sorting does seem to work for me but it's not a popular order. I.e. height gets put before width.

Instead of trying to fix/configure CSSTidy I'd recommend [CSScomb](http://www.csscomb.com/) for sorting.

Comment: Thank you! CSScomb was exactly what I was looking for. It seems that CSSTidy doesn't have the capability to specify the order.